# How do I escape replace string in an ant replaceregexp task?

Tags: regex, ant

Considering this replacement task

```
<property name="unescaped" value="\ regex \\ replacement \1 unfriendly">
<replaceregexp file="..."
               match="..."
               replace="${unescaped}" />
```

The replacement string doesn't get rendered as is (the `\` are gone...)

How do I "escape as literal" the replacement string? can it be done without a `scriptdef`?

Comment: have you find the answer? As I'm having problems with escaping `$` in replace string.

Comment: Sadly, I think I used a JavaScript task to escape the replacement and store it in a new property...